# How do I set Python interpreter options when debugging with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug an IronPython script (my company requires IronPython for some tasks) using Visual Studio Code. The version of IronPython has to be executed using the `-X:Frames` option.

Here's how I would run the script from the command line:

```
ipy -X:Frames my_script.py
```

Adding `-X:Frames` to the "args" launcher property makes it an argument for the script instead of the interpreter which is incorrect:

```
ipy my_script.py -X:Frames
```

Is there a way to pass arguments to the interpreter itself?

If it helps, here's my launch configuration:

```
"launch": {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "My Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "ipy",
            "program": "C:\\temp\\my_script.py",
            "args": ["-X:Frames"],
            "cwd": "C:\\temp",
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "",
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
```

Comment: IIRC, when I had to do something similar, there was an open feature request on this, and the workaround was to create a `.cmd` (Windows) or `.sh` (macOS/Linux) launcher script and put the path to that as your `pythonPath`. (And, even better, you had to create slightly different scripts for debugger `pythonPath` and environment `pythonPath`…) Hopefully there's a better answer now (or I'm remembering wrong), but if not… that should still work.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to pass explicit arguments to the interpreter and not the script itself. See [this feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/941) and please leave a +1 reaction to vote for your desire to see it implemented.